# It's been raining all day

Tags: vocabulary, passive-voice

> **It's been** raining all day.
>
> **It's been** way too long.

What does the meaning of "it is been",
could anyone explain more specific how to use and the meaning of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In these examples, "It's been" is short for "It has been", not "It is been".